# Windows 7 64 Bit. Max USB limit?

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit, bsod, usb-3

Alright so I have computer currently with an Inateck "SuperSpeed" PCI-E expansion card with 4 USB 3.0 Slots. [Link here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B6ZCNGM)

Now we need about 16 pieces of hardware plugged into this machine from a far distance. Our current setup is USB 3.0 Extender that gets its own power that connects to a USB 3.0 hub where each has 3 to 4 additional USB 3.0 slots. Now imagine that for each of those 4 slots. The problem is, it that it is extremely unreliable. If you turn on the machine with everything plugged in we get the blue screen of death. Instead we have to plug everything in, in a very specific order. So that all 16 pieces of hardware are read.

Is there limits to what I am trying to do here? The computer is a simple Dell Inspiron 3650. Is the problem with the motherboard that comes on this machine?

If so what might be some hardware components that I need? Or maybe just point me into the direction of a motherboard that might be able to handle this kind of pressure.

Comment: Devices will consume endpoints based on how many endpoints are available. If you let the devices that can consume lots of endpoints configure first, they will take lots of endpoints, leaving insufficient free endpoints for the devices that need lots of endpoints. You would do better if you used more than one controller rather than one controller with lots of ports.

Comment: "Is there limits to what I am trying to do here?" - Yes; To put it simple, the bigger the distance, the fewer resources you can use.  The use of the extenders, depending on their length, will mean you will be unable to use a single USB 3.0 PCI-E card to connect 16 devices.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks, I didn't think about adding an additional card.

Comment: You didn't describe what this "USB3 extender" is, and how the additional hubs get their power. But so far it looks and smells like you have substantial inrush current from the USB tree. The USB3 controller board looks really cheap, it doesn't have individual port power control, everything is ganged to 5V supply. I would suspect that the USB subsystem drags the 5V power down, disrupting something else to BSOD. Try first to get the USB board power from individual wires from PSU, not from the same cable that goes to HDDs.

Comment: It has it's own power.

Comment: Yes, but how MUCH power?  There is likely to be current limiting.  Can you hang an oscilloscope on the 5V supply, or at least an LED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maximum of 127 peripheral devices per computer. Each hub also counts as a "device". That said, 16 devices via USB should be fine.You could add an additional USB port card. Faster devices like hard drives/flash drives should be shorter and the slower devices on any hubs attached to the PC.

Comment: I would appreciate knowing the source of this number.